# ReactJS Canvas has no captureStream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, capturestream

Is there a way to use captureStream() method in ReactJS canvas? It says no function called captureStream.

I am using canvas with the reference to it. canvasRef.captureStream() is not a function obviously.

Canvas is created by;

```
const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null!)
```

and

```
const stream = canvasRef.current.captureStream();
```

returns there is no function like captureStream() although it appears in the DOM, checkout;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream

Comment: React does not modify DOM Apis. If its there without React, it will be there with it. Without code we cant help any further.

Comment: Hi Slava,

Thank you for your comment, I shared more information about the subject. I am sorry for the misinformation.